# Probability that the size of a subset is "above expected"

Tags: probability

I am reviewing a paper claiming the following statement, and since I'm not familiar with probabilities beyond basic stuff, it puzzles me a lot:

We have a "universe" set $U$ of size $n$ and a subset $S$ of $U$. Each element of $U$ has probability $p$ (a constant) of belonging to $S$. The claim is that, with probability $p$, the size of $S$ is at least $p\cdot n$.

Is there a black-box theorem to justify this? And if it's relevant, there is no proof that the events are actually independent (they *might* be though, It'd need some work to decide for sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the choices of elements is independent, the statement is not true.  Let $p=1-\frac 1{n}+\frac 1{10^n}$.  We can only have $|S|=n$ to meet the constraint, so every element must be in $S$.  The chance of this is $p^{n}\approx 1-e\lt p$  The only way it can be true with this $p$ is if you choose all the elements as a group with probability $p$ and none of them with probability $1-p$ or something close to that.

Answer (score 2):

This is *false*, as [Ross Millikan points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2454445/75808), but holds by replacing $pn$ and $p$ by $\frac{pn}{2}$ and $\frac{p}{2}$ (for instance).

This is an averaging argument. Suppose the probability to have size at least $\frac{pn}{2}$ is strictly smaller than $\frac{p}{2}$. Then, you have

$$
\mathbb{E}[\lvert S\rvert] < n\cdot \frac{p}{2} + \frac{pn}{2}\cdot \left(1-\frac{p}{2}\right) < \frac{pn}{2} + \frac{pn}{2} = pn
$$
which is a contradiction since $\mathbb{E}[\lvert S\rvert]=pn$.

So the probability to have size at least $\frac{pn}{2}$ is at least $\frac{p}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the extra argument, it might come out useful

Comment: @tarulen You're welcome. Averaging arguments pop up very often in the literature, it's a useful thing to know what they refer to.